# How to configure Azure Service Bus Queues to push messages to clients without polling?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am new to Azure Service Bus and I found that I need to continuously poll for Queue messages in order to receive them. However, I want the Queue to push the message to some sort of listener on the client-side of things without it having to poll for messages.

I have read that polling is optional in Azure Service Bus but I couldn't find how to receive messages without it.

Please help if you can. Thank you

Comment: See if this helps: http://fabriccontroller.net/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/.

Comment: I am using .Net core-based applications, I think your link is describing something directly related to .Net Framework-based applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. Take a look on the following to get an idea on how it could be done:

- [Get started with Service Bus topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions)
- [Get started with Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues)

Hope it helps!

Comment: IMHO, this answer does not provide a solution to the problem posted. Rather it provides a general overview of how to use Azure Service Bus queues & topics.

Comment: Don't agree, both links provide detailed examples on how to implement "push" clients.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! However, I would recommend provide a direct link to relevant section (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#5-receive-messages-from-the-subscription).

Comment: I will try the solution and will report back. Thank you for answering

Comment: Okay, I was able to achieve what the documentation specified. Thank you for answering

Comment: @Kenchi This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

> I have read that polling is optional in Azure Service Bus but I couldn't find how to receive messages without it.

Polling is optional if you start receiving on demand. Otherwise, it's not optional and **long-polling** will take place.

> I want the Queue to push the message to some sort of listener on the client-side of things without it having to poll for messages.

There's a way to achieve exactly that using [Event Grid integration with Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept). Service Bus will emit an event to notify about messages awaiting processing and no active listeners. That way your application/system **reacts** and doesn't have to poll.

Note that the key scenario for this feature is low volume of messages that do not need to have a receiver that polls for messages continuously.

Comment: Okay, so in the context of how I would like to use this: I want to build an application using the Microservices architecture and what I understand about communication between microservices, is that they need some kind of message broker to communicate the commands, queries and events. So, my specific question after reading your answer would be: What would be the best tool for achieving such communication, Event Grid or Azure Service Bus?

Comment: Feels like you're asking to design your system via SO comments from a person who doesn't know the system  You _don't_ have to use one or another. You could combine both services, based on your needs. Really depends on use cases. Take events for example. Events are notifications. If you need to notify multiple external subscribers, EG is a better candidate for that. If you need to build internal notification and you control all the subscribers, ASB's pub/sub might be better. If you need commands (singlerecipientt), it could be Storage Queues or ASB queues. Again, your call.