# Is it possible to determine whether a message is locked before attempting to receive it

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am using peek-lock to receive messages using version 7.16.1 of the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK.

I am checking for active messages on a queue using the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` class. The active message count does not consider locks, e.g. it may not be possible to receive an active message because it could be locked.

Given that the `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync` method works by polling the queue until either a message can be received or until the value of the `maxWaitTime` parameter has been exceeded, I would rather not attempt to receive a message unless I know that it is not locked.

I have tried calling `ServiceBusReceiver.PeekMessageAsync` to check the lock before calling `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync`, however, this does not seem to be reliable - sometimes the `LockedUntil` property of a message that I know is locked is set to the default value and other times it seems to reflect a previous lock that has since expired. I wonder if this is a bug in Service Bus or the SDK or if it's simply not something that can be relied upon when peeking messages.

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Have you considered using `ServiceBusProcessor` instead of `ServiceBusReceiver`?

Comment: Why do you need my code? I'm talking about the behaviour when calling the SDK methods directly, none of the code is my own.

Comment: I am intentionally not using ServiceBusProcessor because I need more fine-grain control - I have to control concurrency across receivers for multiple queues, which is not possible with ServiceBusProcessor.

Comment: If you have to "control concurrency across receivers for multiple queues" it sounds like you're defeating the entire point of using a message-passing paradigm...

Comment: Please stay on topic. If you're not interested in answering the question that I posed then there's no need for you to create noise in the comments.

Comment: I'm not trying to derail the conversation, honestly; my point is that it sounds to me like Service Bus isn't the right technology choice for the problem you're trying to solve here. If someone asks me how to drive a car off a cliff, I'm going to first ask them why they want to drive a car off a cliff, because 90% of the time they don't realise that they don't actually need to drive their car off a cliff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported and reliable way to determine if a message is locked before attempting to receive.  Any result that was calculated here would be point-in-time and potentially wrong the moment the calculation completed; the only reliable way is to attempt to acquire the lock.

Have you considered using a nominal value for `maxWaitTime` that would be just a bit above the time needed to accommodate the network transfer of your expected message size?  This would generally be faster and more accurate than making multiple calls.  In the scenario where a connection/link/auth need to be established, those are still governed by the `TryTimeout` of the retry policy and do not need to be accounted for in `maxWaitTime`.

A couple of notes:

- The Service Bus SDK does not calculate or modify the `LockedUntil` time; any value there comes directly from the service.
- Not relevant to the question, but potentially of interest for some - the Service Bus client does not poll.  The attempt to receive a message is a single AMQP operation where the client signals the service and then waits for a message to stream in.  The client gives up and cancels after `maxWaitTime`.
- If you'd like to suggest service features around this, your best bet would be the [Service Bus forum](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/7c0a897d-2125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84) of the Azure Feedback site.

Comment: _"the Service Bus client does not poll"_ - has that always been the case? People talking about polling back in 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299364/how-to-configure-azure-service-bus-queues-to-push-messages-to-clients-without-po

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I'm currently using a nominal value for maxWaitTime as you suggest. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't anything else I can do as I was a bit surprised to discover that the active message count returned by the ServiceBusAdministrationClient included locked messages.

Comment: The active message count is intended more to allow an understanding of how deep the message backlog is for things like scaling decisions.   The lock status is ephemeral and constantly changing.  Even if the counts considered it, you could very well get an answer that is no longer accurate by the time your application interprets it.